# Are there ways to break into a machine if iptables drops all traffic?

Tags: security, iptables

Say I install Linux on an blank computer (no other OS, disk is formatted for installation), and I configure this in iptables:

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

This machine is then directly connected to the internet (internet won't be functional though as no traffic goes in and out).

How secure will this machine be? Are there ways to break in to this machine? Let's define 'break in' as reading any file from this machine.

If the OS matters, feel free to compare how this would behave using the latest Ubuntu Server edition vs. Arch Linux with only the basics installed.

Comment: Is it like asking `Can a ship sink if it's safely anchored(tethered) at the harbour(port)?`. Yes over a period of time if it was built poorly with poor materials or poor design.

Comment: I'm very interested in _how_ a ship can sink in this case, so I hope there is no problem with this question.

Comment: oh, it's a nice question btw.

Answer (score 5):

I would say you would get as secure as it gets without disconnecting the network cable altogether. The only way I can think of how you can still be compromised is if there is a bug in the kernel, iptables module or NIC driver.

Comment: Please elaborate on how the bugs can be exploited in this case assuming a relevant bug(s) for explanation.

Comment: For example there has been an iptables underflow bug which can cause your system to hang:  http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/6U0050ABPY.html & http://securitytracker.com/id/1011854

Comment: Thanks. But would this bug only cause a machine to hang or could files be exposed? I am most interested in ways third parties could extract information from my computer even though iptables is run as strict as possible.

Comment: This bug would cause the machine to hang. Admittedly it all *very* theoretical, and I don't think you would run any realistic risks to data exposure.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious one is IPv6, if there is some vulnerable server listening on that protocol. Any other network protocol could be a culprit.

You don't need to drop all IPv4 traffic to secure a machine from remote attacks. It's sufficient to not run any vulnerable service. A default installation of any decent OS is fine in this respect.

If you're paranoid and don't trust the software you use to be reasonably bug-free, then don't use a computer at all. The standard advice is to keep it powered off, but that's not quite enough: your BIOS might have a [buggy wake-on-LAN](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/unix-servers-possible-intrusions-or-attacks-that-do-not-use-any-of-the-open-lis/1381#1381) (a case where a powered-off computer is exploitable, and switching it on removes the vulnerability!).

Comment: Do you have a link to the IPv6 info? Is there a way to block this as well using iptables? Is all IPv6 traffic accepted by default using the iptables configuration I posted? Note that I'm not asking this because I am paranoid of using a computer - I just would like to understand the theoretical power and limitations of strict iptables rules.

Comment: @user `iptables` blocks IPv4. That's its job. There is a similar `iptables6` for IPv6. Seeing the iptables configuration doesn't say anything about IPv6. For both protocols, by default, the firewall is open. I don't know what IPv6 services run by default, presumably at least SSH if you install `sshd`.